# Since upgrade to Natty, no longer automatically booting from drive at startup

Tags: 11.04, boot, bios

As the subject suggests, I now have to enter the boot menu in BIOS in order to be able to boot Ubuntu. This has happened since I upgraded to Natty. Is there a way to automatically boot from the correct drive without this manual intervention? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Check your bios settings. Make sure they are set to the drive where you have ubuntu installed by default. Unfortunately the bios screens vary from computer to computer so it's hard to give detailed instructions.